# Terraform variable definition

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I would like to create a deployments input and drive my deployments based on that var.
Here's an example deployments input,

> ```
> deployments = {
>     dev-1 = {
>         dev-api-us = {
>             hosts = ["dev-api-us.lm.com", "dev-api-us.lm1.com"]
>         }
>         region = "us-east1"
>     }
>     dev-2 = {
>         dev-api-uk = {
>             hosts = ["dev-api-uk.lm.com", "dev-api-uk.lm1.com"]
>         }
>         region = "europe-west2"
>     }
> }
> ```

Is that a valid input if so what will the corresponding variable definition look like?

I tried this, but it says the syntax isn't right

> ```
> variable "deployments" {
>   description = "A map of deployment"
>   type = map(map(object({
>         hosts = list(string)
>       })
>     region = string
>     ))
> }
> ```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data structure is a bit confusing because the second level seems to be a mixture of predefined attributes (`region`) and arbitrary map keys (like `dev-api-us` and `dev-api-uk`).

I think the best way to proceed here would be to change this structure so that the second level of map is separate from the object it's embedded in. You didn't mention a noun in your question to refer to `dev-api-us` and `dev-api-uk` are examples of, so I'm going to just call them "host prefixes" for the sake of having something to call them:

```
{
  dev-1 = {
    host_prefixes = {
      dev-api-us = {
        hosts = ["dev-api-us.lm.com", "dev-api-us.lm1.com"]
      }
    }
    region = "us-east1"
  }
  dev-2 = {
    host_prefixes = {
      dev-api-uk = {
        hosts = ["dev-api-uk.lm.com", "dev-api-uk.lm1.com"]
      }
    }
    region = "europe-west2"
  }
}
```

A suitable type constraint for this adjusted data structure could be:

```
variable "deployments" {
  type = map(object({
    host_prefixes = map(object({
      hosts = set(string)
    }))
    region = string
  }))
}
```

This altered structure works within Terraform's type system because it separates the object-typed parts from the map-typed parts. The Terraform language doesn't have any type constraint that allows both map and object behaviors to be combined into a single value.